Change app's icon by script
On Sonoma 14.5. I have some apps that I want to a set custom icon for. This is easy enough to do in Finder -- right click on the app, choose get info, and drag and drop the icon I want into the icon in the get info window. However, when the app updates, the icon reverts to the default and this has to be done again. Obviously I want to automate this.
I tried an app called Pictogram but it doesn't seem to be working. No applications show up. I tried using the shell to copy the icon into the app's resource folder but got permission denied, even with sudo.
Finally, I tried to tackle this in Applescript, using variations of this
tell application "Finder"
    -- pseudo code
    set icon of <application> to <icon>
end tell

but could not get it to work. Finally, I resorted to UI scripting. Basically I replicated the drag and drop icon into get info window in code. The function is below. It copies the icon to the clipboard, opens the app's get info window, moves focus to the icon, presses cmd+v to paste, then refreshes the dock
    -- Function to set the icon for a given application
    on setAppIcon(appPath, iconPath)
        -- Convert POSIX paths to Finder file references
        set appFile to POSIX file appPath as alias
        set iconFile to POSIX file iconPath as alias

        -- Check if the application exists
        tell application "Finder"
            if not (exists appFile) then
                display notification "Application not found: " & appPath with title "Replicons"
                return false
            end if
        end tell

        -- Check if the icon file exists
        tell application "Finder"
            if not (exists iconFile) then
                display notification "Icon file not found: " & iconPath with title "Replicons"
                return false
            end if
        end tell

        -- make the Dock think the icon has changed
        do shell script "touch \"" & iconPath & "\""
        -- Copy the icon file to the clipboard
        do shell script "osascript -e 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file \"" & iconPath & "\") as «class icns»)'"

        -- Open the "Get Info" window for the application
        tell application "Finder"
            open information window of appFile
        end tell

        -- Delay to ensure the "Get Info" window is open
        delay 0.3

        -- Use System Events to interact with the "Get Info" window
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Finder"
                -- Select the "Get Info" window
                set infoWindow to the first window whose name contains "Info"

                -- Press Tab to select the icon in the window
                keystroke tab

                -- Delay to ensure the icon is selected
                delay 0.1

                -- Paste the new icon from the clipboard
                keystroke "v" using command down
            end tell
        end tell

        -- Delay to observe the change
        -- delay 3

        -- Close the "Get Info" window
        tell application "Finder"
            close (the first window whose name contains "Info")
        end tell

        return true
    end setAppIcon

-- List of applications and corresponding icons
set appIconPairs to {¬
    {"/Applications/Google Chrome Beta.app", "/Volumes/T7/Downloads/chromium.icns"}, ¬
    {"/Applications/Google Chrome.app", "/Volumes/T7/Downloads/chrome.icns"}, ¬
    {"/Applications/foobar2000.app", "/Volumes/T7/Downloads/foobar2000.icns"}}

-- Activate Finder and set it to frontmost
tell application "Finder"
    activate
end tell

-- Loop through each application and set the corresponding icon
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
end tell

set successCount to 0

repeat with appIconPair in appIconPairs
    set {appPath, iconPath} to appIconPair
    if setAppIcon(appPath, iconPath) then
        set successCount to successCount + 1
    end if
end repeat


if successCount > 0 then
    -- Restart the Dock to refresh the icons
    do shell script "killall Dock"
    display dialog "Successfully replaced " & (successCount as string) & " icons." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
else
    display dialog "No change made."
end if


This is clunky. Can I do better?
Thanks in advance

Using the answer from @wch1zpink , I was able to come up with a solution that uses the Foundation framework instead of UI scripting. There's a caveat: it works when run in Automator but not as a standalone app. To do that, it needs to be signed ad hoc (Replicons.app is name of my app.)
xattr -cr /Applications/Replicons.app && codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Replicons.app

Then, it needs to be granted full disk access by manually adding it to
Settings > Privacy & security > Full disk access
At least this is the case on Sonoma 14.5
The script in full
(*
 This applescript allows bulk setting custom icons for apps (or folders)
 It cannot set icons for system apps like Safari
   or apps you do not own such as those installed from the App store
 Tested working on Sonoma 14.5

 USAGE: Create a text file called replicons.cfg in your Documents folder
 following this format

<app1-posix-full-path>,<icon1-posix-full-path>
<app2-posix-full-path>,<icon2-posix-full-path>
...

 Icon may be of type .icns or an image type such as .png

 Example:

/Applications/Google Chrome.app,/Volumes/T7/icons/chrome dark.icns
/Applications/foobar2000.app,/Volumes/T7/Downloads/foobar2000.icns
/Applications/Spotify.app,/Users/me/Documents/icons/Spotify.png

 To revert an icon to the default, leave the icon field empty (note the comma)

/Applications/Spotify.app,

 Do not leave blank lines or leading / trailing white spaces.

 Stackexchange discussion
 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/473597/change-apps-icon-by-script

 CAVEAT: to run as a stand alone app (as opposed to inside Automator), I found that the app
 has to be signed

 xattr -cr /Applications/appname.app && codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/appname.app

 and granted full disk access by manually adding it to
 Settings > Privacy & security > Full disk access
*)

use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set configFile to (path to home folder as text) & "Documents:replicons.cfg"

-- Function to set the icon for a given application
on setAppIcon(appPath, iconPath)
    try
        -- the magic happens here
        if iconPath is "" then
            set image to missing value
        else
            set image to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initByReferencingFile:iconPath
        end if
        set success to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's setIcon:image forFile:appPath options:0
        return success
    on error errStr number errorNumber
        display dialog errStr
        return false
    end try
end setAppIcon

-- Parse a line from the config file
on parseLine(aLine)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
    set parsedList to text items of aLine
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return parsedList
end parseLine

-- Read the appIconPairs from an external text file
set appIconPairs to {}

try
    set fileContents to read (configFile as alias)
    set fileLines to paragraphs of fileContents

    repeat with aLine in fileLines
        if aLine is not "" then
            set {appPath, iconPath} to my parseLine(aLine)
            copy {appPath, iconPath} to end of appIconPairs
        end if
    end repeat

on error errStr number errorNumber
    display dialog errStr
    return
end try

set successCount to 0

repeat with appIconPair in appIconPairs
    set {appPath, iconPath} to appIconPair
    if setAppIcon(appPath, iconPath) then
        set successCount to successCount + 1
    end if
end repeat

if successCount > 0 then
    -- Restart the Dock to refresh the icons
    do shell script "killall Dock"
    display dialog "Successfully replaced " & (successCount as string) & " icons."
else
    display dialog "No change made."
end if



This following solution is not exactly what you may be looking for but I think it is enough to set you on the right path.
This following AppleScript code uses the fileicon shell script utility.  If fileicon is not installed on your system, it can easily be installed in Terminal.app with Homebrew using the command Brew install fileicon
All about Homebrew
All about fileicon
activate
set chosenApp to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file with prompt ¬
    "Choose The Application Whose Icon You Would Like To Change" of type "APPL")

activate
set iconFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file of type "com.apple.icns" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The Replacement .icns File")

try
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/fileicon rm " & chosenApp
end try

try
    set theResult to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/fileicon set " & chosenApp & " " & iconFile
on error errMsg number errNum
    return
end try

activate
display dialog theResult buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"

SOME THINGS TO TAKE NOTE OF:

The fileicon utility is not limited to only using ".icns" files.
Make sure you use the correct path for your installation of
fileicon, in the do shell script commands.
This version does not alter the application bundle. It also adds the Icon? file to the base directory.



Thank you, but I've tried fileicon before. It fails
sudo fileicon set /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Beta.app/ ~/Downloads/google\ dark.icns
Password:
fileicon: ERROR: Cannot modify '/Applications/Google Chrome Beta.app/': you do not have write permissions.

I've also tried iconset https://github.com/tale/iconset and it fails similarly. I ls -l /Applications and it shows me as owner of Google Chrome Beta.app/ and admin as group

@JBart I just download the Google Chrome Beta.app and tested my code, without the need of having to use sudo, my solution works perfectly.  Try using my code exactly as I have it in the post.

You should not alter files in an application bundle, as that may break the code signing.  Also, the Finder's scripting dictionary shows the icon property as being a bitmap, so you would need to generate the data for that.
Setting an icon for a folder (such as an application package) adds a Icon\r file to the base directory, which doesn't change any of the files, so some AppleScriptObjC can be used for NSWorkspace's setIcon:forFile:options: method.  I tested the following script with some applications that have me as the owner, but you would still need administrative access for other items in the /Applications folder.  Holding down the option key when running the script will remove the custom icon:
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on run -- example
   set currentFlags to current application's NSEvent's modifierFlags() as integer
   set mask to current application's NSAlternateKeyMask as integer
   set optionKeyDown to ((currentFlags div mask) mod 2) as boolean
   if optionKeyDown then
      set choicePrompt to "Choose a file to reset the icon:"
   else
      set choicePrompt to "Choose a file to set the icon:"
   end if
   set theFile to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt choicePrompt)
   if optionKeyDown then
      set image to missing value
   else
      set iconFile to POSIX path of (choose file of type "public.image" with prompt "Choose an image file for the icon:")
      set image to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initByReferencingFile:iconFile
   end if
   set success to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace's setIcon:image forFile:theFile options:0
end run

